# Unit Test, How to mock on existing EF 5.0 on existing web form C#.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing the Unit Test on Business layer of an old web form C#.net application (4.0) project. This application has E.F 5.0 (Database first) for connecting to Database.  It is pretty big application.

I don't want to re-design and re engineering on the whole application by adding Interface, UnitOfWork, and Repository for mocking the database.  what the simple and quick way to mock Existing E.F 5.0 (Database First) for unit test project?

Answer (score 0):

You can just mock virtual method and interfaces, I am afraid you will at least need to create a interface wrapper for that database and refactor the references